# How to use and install DingTalk on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04

How to use  and install DingTalk  on Ubuntu 16.04?

I have tried with some information in this [link](https://github.com/nashaofu/dingtalk). 
but It is not successful.

Looking for : command line to install dingtalk ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any working command line solution to install DingTalk in Ubuntu but I find some alternate like chrome app.

I am able to add following chrome app and user like native app. 
Steps : 
Add DingTalk app in your chrome app with given this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dingtalk/olkecappebifjdpfkbccmmhbabeidcfe?addtag=browser).

And follow below screenshots we will be user DingTalk in nay OS with Chrome browser like Native app.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Lunch app and Scan QR code from mobile version of app from your Mobile device Dingtalk it will works.

If any one find alternate which is better then this please share.

I have found one more [link](https://github.com/jamasBian/DingTalk-linux) Try it if work for others, But I have tried but it did not work for me.

Comment: Does this solution make it possible to have video calls?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution using ***Wine*** you can install the **Ding Talk** window version in Ubuntu. for that, you follow some Steps.

> **Step 1** :- first  install  the Wine

```
Sudo apt update
Sudo apt install wine
```

> **Step 2** :- Now Download the [ding talk](https://www.dingtalk.com/static/i18ndownload) window  file

> **Step 3** :-  Now go to the download folder of the open terminal and run that command

```
Sudo wine Dingtalk.exe  ##specific your download
```

> **Step 4** :-Follow the installation process:
> The program's installer should now run as if it were on a Windows system. Follow the on-screen instructions to install the program.

> **Step 5** :-Access the program:
> Once the installation is complete, you can usually find the program's executable file in the Wine virtual drive. The default path is usually /home/your_username/.wine/drive_c/. You can access it using the terminal or a file manager.

> **Step 6** :-Run the program:
> To run the installed program, use the wine command followed by the path to the program's executable file. For example:

```
wine /home/your_username/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/ProgramName/program.exe
```

Replace /Program\ Files/ProgramName/program.exe with the actual path to the program's executable.